# Scrape javascript second variable using php

Tags: php

I'm trying to take the contents of a page contained in a javascript code. What I need is the second variable `myfile=[{CONTENT I NEED}];` (if you look at the first two are empty) I need more precisely the content immediately after `myfile=[{CONTENT I NEED}];`

```
myvideo="",myfile="",myvideo="";myfile=[{CONTENT I NEED}];
```

my php

```
preg_match('#myfile= (.*?);\s*$#m', $file_content, $result);
echo $result[1];
```

Comment: your preg_match has a space after myfile= , but the example you want to match against doesn't have a space

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 1  same problem

Comment: look into http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: You should sort out your indentation to make the code readable and post your error. Is this a question on how to use `preg_match()`? If so you would help yourself by putting this in your description

Comment: this works but return also more content after }]; <----- for example  [{CONTENT I NEED}]; other javascript code. I need exactly only the content inside [{HERE}];

Answer (score 0):

```
$s = 'myvideo="",myfile="",myvideo="";myfile=[{CONTENT I NEED}];';
preg_match_all('/.*myfile=(.*);.*/', $s, $results);
echo $results[1][0];
```

gives:

```
[{CONTENT I NEED}]
```

Comment: my answer suggested using preg_match_all, not preg_match - that will be grabbing the first match. Try what I suggested, against $file_content instead of the $s that I used in the example

Comment: all you should need to do is replace the last 2 lines from your original question with:
    preg_match_all('/.*myfile=(.*);.*/', $file_content, $results);
    echo $results[1][0];

Comment: try adding a U (non-greedy) after the end of the pattern: preg_match_all('/.*myfile=(.*);.*/U', $file_content, $results)

Comment: what does $file_content actually contain?